# Is EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 different, if compiling Haskell locally?

Tags: haskell, amazon-ec2

So I want to compile a Haskell program locally, and then upload it to my EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 (free trial) instance.

My question is, will it work on EC2 if I compile my haskell program on an official Ubuntu 12.04 distribution (say in virtualbox)?
Or do I need exactly the same version of Ubuntu as Amazon is running? Do it have to have the exact same set of updates etc..?

P.S. If yes - where do I get the Amazon's version of Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the right answer to this question, but you could use ldd to check which libraries (and versions) your executable expects to exist and make sure Amazon's Ubuntu has those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do this on a regular basis, it should work just fine. Just make sure you're using the same architecture (32- or 64-bit).

You can get a list of the different Ubuntu AMIs at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide

Comment: Thanks! But why do I need a list of ubuntu AMIs? I mean I know which AMI my instance is using just by inspecting it in the control panel, right?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your PS was asking for the list of AMIs, I misunderstood apparently.

Comment: Tried compiling on my Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtualbox and then copying to Ec2 Ubuntu 12.04 installation - it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official Ubuntu AMIs from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/, you have the exact same binaries as the official Ubuntu distribution (as long as the architecture is the same: 32-bit or 64-bit). The only difference should be which packages are installed by default (so you might need to install a few extra packages). And as long as both are kept updated, both will also have the exact same set of updates.

Even if you are using AMIs created by someone else, it should still be the same; I believe most Ubuntu AMIs would be created by installing the official Ubuntu distribution.